# What does this notation mean? $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{3}$

Tags: graph-theory, notation, modular-arithmetic

In a question in graph theory I am given: $\text {Let } X=\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{3}$

However, the notation has not been defined or made clear. I am guessing the subscript means it is the integers mod 2 but what is the exponent in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z_2^3\,$ can mean $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$, the set of triplets of elements of $\mathbb Z_2$.

I.e.,  $X=\{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Thank you. Another part of the question defines $\mathcal{B}=\left\{(a, b, c, d) \in X^{4} | a+b+c+d=0(\bmod 2)\right\}$. So I'm guessing the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are matrices in this case?

Comment: I would guess that too